# Replace a hyperlink with an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to replace internal links:

```
<div class="activityinstance">
    <a href="http://website.com/hvp/view.php?id=515512">activity</a>
</div>
```

to become:

```
    <div class="activityinstance">
        <iframe src="http://website.com/hvp/view.php?id=515512">
           activity
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

I have been able to replace just the text with an iframe using jquery.
https://codepen.io/alanpt/pen/mWJvoB

But this is proving to be quite hard.

Another difficulty is that it needs to only be links with hvp in the address.

I appreciate any help - thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a regex and `replace` and over complicating things. Just get the href using `attr` and remove the link and append an iframe.

Comment: Inn your code above, you have an anchor (`<a>`) inside the divs. But in the codepin code you don't have them!

Comment: The only thing that is allowed in between an iframe tag is plain text, and that text is only rendered when a browser does not support an iframe (which is never nowadays) . So it's useless to what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks zer00ne. I'll edit the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is the regex I am using to get the right address:

`/(https?:\/\/website.com\/hvp\/view.php\?id=.*)/ig `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample of:

```
<div class="activityinstance">
    <a href="http://website.com/hvp/view.php?id=515512">activity</a>
</div>
```

[Because of a fact that having HTML inside of an IFRAME tags has no bearing, and is a complete waste of bytes, we will leave it out. And because this solution doesn't need wrappers, we'll stick to the good old (plain and clean) JavaScript].

**The snippet:**

```
[].slice.call(document.links).
    forEach( 
        function( a ) {
        if( a.href.match(/hvp/) ) {
            a.outerHTML = "<iframe src=" + a.href + "><\/iframe>" 
        }
    } );
```

will result in clean HTML such as:

```
<div class="activityinstance">
    <iframe src="http://website.com/hvp/view.php?id=515512"></iframe>
</div>
```

...of course, without indentations and unnecessary white-spaces.

Comment: @Alan Proctor-Thomson
here is a forked demo of your codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJvbaw

Comment: Thanks for the help. I liked that it uses vanilla Javascript and that it's very readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').ready(function(){
    $('.activityinstance a').each(function(){                    // get all the links inside the .activeinstance elements
        var $this = $(this);                                     // ...
        var $parent = $this.parent();                            // get the parent of the link
        var href = $this.attr('href');                           // get the href of the link
        if(href.indexOf('/hvp/') == -1) return;                  // if the href doesn't contain '/hvp/' then skip the rest of this function (where the replacement happens)

        $this.remove();                                          // remove the link as I don't see any reasong for it to be inside the iframe
        $parent.append('<iframe src="' + href + '"></iframe>');  // add an iframe with the src set to the href to the parent of the link
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks ibrahim. But it needs to only work on links with "hvp" in it, not any other link. That is why I am using regex.

Comment: Thanks ibrahim. That worked a treat. And thanks for the helpful code comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('a').replaceWith(function () {
            var content = this;
            return $('<iframe src="about:blank;">').one('load', function () {
                $(this).contents().find('body').append(content);
            });
        });
```